# Saving and Loading ObservableList in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, save, load, offline, observablelist

I made an Application in JavaFX which has two different TableViews. These TableViews are connected. The Table View "Dealers" has variables like String name, String Adress etc., but it also has an ObservableList of rating Objects. These Rating Objects are dynamically displayed in the other TableView trough listeners which react to the seller which is selected.

I need an easy way to save and load these Seller Objects. Using JDBC i tried to setup a database but couldn't deal with the ObjectList variable in the Seller Object. I am a beginner in Java programming and a simple offline save and load option would be enough.

My Question: What is the simplest  way to offline store and and load these Seller Objects?

Thank you in advance.

[Image of JavaFX Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XopcS.png)

Comment: the simplest way is a database (sqlite is the perfect solution for similar tasks). but it requires more complex knowledge. another option is to serialize collections directly.

Comment: Of course a db can be used for this purpose. You need 2 tables for this and the query gets a bit more complex than simply recalling data from a single table, but it shouldn't be too difficult either. A framework like hibernate could do this for you, but this seems like an ovekill in the given situation. There are many other possibilities such as JaxB, GSON, ect...

Comment: @fabian Thank you, I will look into connecting my application with a database then.